# VB.NET - DataSet, DataGrid and XML - Selecting tables and rows

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagrid, dataset

So far I have been using text-files to store data in my application. They are sort of comma separated. I used a ListView and quite some code to present the data.

Today I found out about the DataSet and DataGrid components. I'd love to use them. My data could then be stored in XML, which is nice since the server does that also.

Not sure how to get it working though. I have a simple hierarchy:

```
<myapp>
  <user>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
  </user>
  <collection>
    <name>Beer cans</name>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Heineken</name>
    </item>
  </collection>
  <collection>
    <name>Coffee mugs</name>
    <item>
      <id>18</id>
      <name>Starbucks</name>
    </item>
  </collection>
</myapp>
```

Normally I would wrap the collection elements in parent element, but that seems to complicate things in VB.NET. Anyways. My question is...

If I have a list of collections in my app that the user can click on, I would love to show in a DataGrid all the items in that collection.

My code so far somewhat selects the right collection, but I cant seem to get to the items themselves for instance:

```
Dim DataSet As New DataSet
DataSet.ReadXml("c:\john.doe.xml")
MainGrid.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("collection").Select("name='" & selName & "'")
```

(edit: typo's)

Answer (score 1):

```
    If NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then
        Dim cl As New WebClient
        AddHandler cl.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf cl_DownloadStringCompleted
        Dim url As String = "Your link in here"
        cl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(url))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("check your internet connection first")
    End If

Private Sub cl_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result)
For Each result In doc.<myapp>.<user>
        TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text & Environment.NewLine & result.<firstname>.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
Dim CollectionTable As DataTable = DataSet.Tables("collection")
Dim CollectionSelection As DataRow() = CollectionTable.Select("name='" & selName & "'")
Dim CollectionID As Integer

If CollectionSelection.Count = 1 Then
    CollectionID = CollectionSelection(0)("collection_id")
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

MainGrid.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("item").Select("collection_id =" & CollectionID).CopyToDataTable()
```

Your DataSet is reading your xml and is creating 3 tables `user` , `collection` and `item`. the `item` table has 3 columns `id` `name` `collection_id`. so what I did was selecting the collection_id based on the collection name and selecting the item based on that id. Note that the collection table has columns `name` and `collection_id`.